# MySQL Not Working No Extracting Information?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, while-loop

I am working on a school project but I am having trouble with this block of code. Although I cant allow you guys to access my database, can you please try to find any syntax error or anything I am doing wrong. All I am getting is a blank space and any echoed text out of the loops.

```
<?php
$app= mysql_query("SELECT View FROM Stat");
echo "<table><tr>";

while($app_loop = mysql_fetch_array($app)){
    $db_item = $app_loop['Item'];

        $apps= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Title='$db_item'");}
            while($apps_loop = mysql_fetch_array($apps)){
                $db_icon = $apps_loop['Icon'];
                $db_title = $apps_loop['Title'];

echo"<td>
    <form method='post' action='AppCatPage.php'>
    <input type='image' src='$db_icon' width='50px' height='50px' id='sb'>
    <input type='hidden' value='$db_title' name='apptitleu'>
    </form> 
    </td>"; 
}
echo"</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: There's no connection here to the database. Perhaps that's what's wrong?

Comment: there is a connection this is not my whole doucment the connection is in a php include at the top of the page.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with your problem but why not use a join instead of a loop? But don't bother responding to that - i probably won't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $app= mysql_query("SELECT View FROM Stat");

you selected only View column from table stat

```
$db_item = $app_loop['Item'];
```

but you are trying to read content of 'Item' Column
change first line to:

```
$app= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stat");
```

i think this is the problem ...

Comment: that make sense thank you it should be like                        $app= mysql_query("SELECT View, Item FROM Stat");                correct